# htaccess redirect url query string to other string parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I already have htaccess working to redirect spaces `%20` with `+` symbols in the query string. Then I have another rule to redirect from one directory to another.

example:

`http://Mysite/domestic-jobs/?domestic=val or otherVal`

will be redirected to

`http://Mysite/jobs/?domestic=val+or+otherVal`

Now I need another rule to include in my htaccess file that redirects the query string parameter after the `?` from `?domestic=` to `?position=`. How can I do this without interrupting the other rules in the file?

example:

`http:/Mysite/domestic-jobs/?domestic=val or otherVal`

I need to be redirected to

`http:/site/jobs/?position=val+or+otherVal`

Here is what I have so far.

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)%20(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1+%2 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^domestic-jobs/(.*)$ /jobs/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Jon Lin's answer worked. Just had to add the Cond and Rule after my first Cond and Rule that already exists in my htaccess file. Otherwise it wasn't redirecting properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under `RewriteEngine On` just add:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^domestic=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?position=%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks. what if I have more than just ?domestic=. say I have ?blah= and ?blahblah= and ?blahblahblah= and want to change all to ?position=. Is there a wild card or something I can use that will change anything after the ? to use ?position= if ?position= isn't already after the ?

Comment: Change `domestic=` to `[^=]+=`

Comment: hmmm, it caused an infinite loop to occur. It has to redirect only if not `?position=`.

Comment: My bad, `(?!position)[^=]+=`

Comment: ya that works good. I have this rule `RewriteRule ^.*-jobs/(.*)$ /jobs/$1 [R=301,NC,L]` which redirects all requests from directory that matches -jobs. Example: /programming-jobs/ etc gets redirected to /jobs/. Now my question is how can I redirect all requests with a query string that does not have a directory. In other words, that append the `?` after the `/` in the root of the site. After the `.com/` but only redirect if there is a query string appended after the `.com/?`